# Distribution of white caramels thrown away from a bag of white and black caramels (probability problem)

Tags: probability

> Suppose we have a bag containing $m$ white and $n$ black caramels. We pic a caramel and if it is white, we eat it, otherwise we put it back in the bag. If we take out $r$ black caramels succesively, then we believe that we have eaten all the white caramels and we throw the bag. What is the distribution of the number of white caramels thrown away?

**Attempt** Let $W, B$ be the events we pic a white, a black caramel, respectively. The scenario we throw away $m-w$ white caramels, where $w=0,1,2,\ldots,m$ may be described as:

$$B^{[r-1]}W B^{[r-1]} W \ldots B^{[r-1]}WB^k$$

($w$ appearences of $W$) where $B^{[r-1]}=B^0$ or $B$ or $B^2$ or $\ldots$ or $B^{r-1}$

and $B^k=\underbrace{BB\ldots B}_{k ~times}$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,r-1.$

There are $0+1+\ldots+(r-1)=(r-1)r/2$ possible combinations for $B$ each time so the desired probability is:

$$\frac{(r-1)r}{2}\frac{n}{n+m}\cdot \frac{m}{n+m}\cdot \frac{(r-1)r}{2}\frac{n}{n+m-1} \cdot\frac{m-1}{n+m-1}\,\ldots \frac{(r-1)r}{2}\frac{n}{n+m-(w-1)} \cdot\frac{m-(w-1)}{n+m-(w-1)}\cdot \bigg(\frac{n}{n+m-w}\bigg)^r.$$

Is my solution correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's not correct, as it yields $0$ if you substitute $r=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that all of white caramels will be thrown away is $(\frac{n}{m+n})^r$.

The probability that exactly one will be eaten is $(1-(\frac{n}{m+n})^r)(\frac{n}{m+n-1})^r.$

The probability that exactly two will be eaten is $(1-(\frac{n}{m+n})^r)(1-(\frac{n}{m+n-1})^r)(\frac{n}{m+n-2})^r.$

In general, letting $p_k = (\frac{n}{m+n-k})^r$, then the probability that $k$ white caramels are eaten is $(1-p_0)\cdot (1-p_1)\cdots (1-p_{k-1})\cdot p_k$, for $0\le k\le m$.

Comment: @joriki I am pretty sure it is correct. Think about it in phases, where each phase is fewer than $r$ black draws followed by a single white draw, or is r black draws. The probability of the latter is $p_k$. Since the only other option is the former, the probability is $1-p_k$.

Comment: Yes, I removed my comment because I realized that :-)

Comment: Very nice. My question is: where do you evaluate the probabilities $\frac{m-k}{n+m-k}$ of eating white caramels (if we have already eaten $k$ of them)?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Those are rolled into the $1-p_i$ factors. If you do not eat r black caramels in a row, it means you must have eaten a white caramel.